# How do I use POST with htaccess rewriterule?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a rewriterule in my htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^Signup$ /dst2/signup.php
```

I would like to use POST instead of GET for the data that gets passed by this form.

The rule above, however, sends the data as a GET.

Is there a way to use a POST with a rewriterule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to reroute a GET action to a POST action with mod_rewrite. If you're sending a POST through a rewrite rule, it should end up being a POST when you're done. If you're sending a GET and trying to change it into a POST, change your system.

Comment: I agree, if your page sends a POST request that rule will send a POST request too.